# Как получить права на удаление папки?

Tags: python, права-доступа

Я пытаюсь удалить файл через код на python, все удаляет! Но если я пытаюсь удалить папку пишет нет прав! Как дать права? Я пытался .py в .exe и запустить от имени админа, но нет. Как дать права файлу .py?

Comment: Я удаляю папку командой os.remove(папка).

Comment: Мне главное не админку файлу а удалить папку.

Comment: Если удалять папку нужно воспользоваться функцией `os.rmdir`, а не `os.remove`

Comment: а прав хватит ?

Comment: а разве rmdir не удаляет путь? Функция rmdir() модуля os удаляет путь к каталогу path

Comment: rmdir не удалит все файлы и папку входящие в этот путь? папка1\папка2\папка3 - удлаиться только папака3?

Comment: все понял, воспользуйтесь функцией `rmtree` модуля `shutil`. Но это только для папок.

Comment: rmtree - удалит папку на конце пути? да? не все папку на пути?

Comment: просто очень боюсь удалить лишнее, в корзине же это не появится)

Comment: Конечно в конце.